# Proguard - can't find referenced method

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have to upgrade my build tool to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3` with `gradle 4.4`. My project worked well with `proguard` previously. But after upgrading, there are a lot of issues as the one below:

```
MainActivity: can't find referenced method 'void setAlpha(float)' in program class android.view.View
...can't find referenced method 'void execute(java.lang.Runnable)' in program class android.os.AsyncTask
...can't find referenced method 'void overridePendingTransition(int,int)'
...can't find referenced method 'boolean canPause()' in program class android.widget.VideoView
Warning: library class android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo depends on program class android.os.Parcelable$Creator
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable extends or implements program class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

What did I miss in my proguard file?

After taking a lot of time looking at the log cat, I saw that every `referenced method` was `Added in API level 11 or above` (I am using if/else check) and my `min sdk` was `15`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Proguard version is updated with the buildtools, maybe this is an issue with that Proguard version. Have you tried to downgrade (or updgrade) manually your Proguard version to see if the error still occurs ?

override it like this

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:x.x.x' //here use whatever version you'd like
        }
    }
}
```

and look up your proguard version like this

```
./gradlew buildEnvironment
```